# CSS won't work with Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, flask

I have been working with flask trying to get the css properties to work but even though the css file is being included, the properties don't reflect on the elements.

cards.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename = 'script/checkers.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename = 'script/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js')}}">             
     </script>
           <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename = 'checkers.css')}}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">

        </div>
        <div id="glow">

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The CSS is all there but it doen't work. The file is included but it doesn't show the properties.

CSS: checkers.css

```
 #board
 {
     height:300px;
     width:300px;
     background-color:black;
 }
 body
 {
     background-color:white;
 }
 div
 {
     background-color:black;
     height:300px;
     width:300px;
 }
 .glow
 {
     border:2px solid blue;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the file is definitely included`? How have you determined this?

Comment: Are you sure the css is actually being included in the finished html? When you hit the page in a browser and view the source can you see the actual css file?

Comment: BTW, you have ".glow" will hit classes named glow, you're using id=glow not class=glow

Comment: Is checkers.css located at `static/checkers.css`?

Comment: yes. after going to the page in the web browser, the css file is actually there. I am able to click on its link from the main page and the css file is shown. the css properties are not showing  
this link takes you to what i'm taking about http://tman.kd.io:9002/

Comment: its in  static/style/checkers.css

Comment: In chrome use the javascript console and go to the network tab. Here you can see if your CSS file is being correctly fetched. It is faster and more informative than going into the source and clicking the link itself.

Comment: @cpb2 i checked the network tab and i dont see the css file there. if that is the issue, how do would one correct this?

Comment: If your CSS is not there at all, you can conclude that there is something wrong with the declaration of the CSS include. Read: the HTML is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem related to Flask.

An HTML `<link` tag requires the `rel` attribute to be set to `stylesheet`. In your case the browser will have a `<link` element it its DOM, but (lacking the `rel="stylesheet"`) it won't know what to do with it.

A solution to your problem is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='checkers.css')}}"/>
```

That said, you have to put the `checkers.css` file right in your `/static/` folder in your flask project (i.e. `/static/checkers.css`).

Comment: What do you mean regarding the location

Comment: it works regards of it being in /static/ or in /static/style/

Comment: either the real file exists in both locations or there's some caching going on (either server- or client-side). Try with a "Private/Incognito Browsing" window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Open the html page with browser and check from source code if the generated link to the css file is right or not.